# Label `overflow' multiply defined when compiling tex

Tags: visual-studio-code, tex, defined

I'm trying to compile my tex file, but it keeps giving me this error.

```
Label `overflow' multiply defined.
```

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels are used to create cross-references to sections, figures, and such. The warning suggests that when you search your tex file for `\label{overflow}`, you will find more than one. Rename them so that they are unique. They need to be in order to be referenced properly using `\ref{...}`.